# Conflicting FIELD statements in QB64

Tags: qb64

When running this code it seems testfile.000 contains "00" and testfile.001 contains "99", so, why is there no conflict between these files?? Should it throw a "duplicate definition."?

```
file1$ = "testfile.000"
file2$ = "testfile.001"
OPEN file1$ FOR RANDOM AS #1 LEN = 2
FIELD #1, 2 AS x$
OPEN file2$ FOR RANDOM AS #2 LEN = 2
FIELD #2, 2 AS x$
LSET x$ = "99"
PUT 1, 1
PUT 2, 1
END
```

Comment: That is: why does it not assign "99" to both file #1 and file #2?

Comment: In BASIC (also GW Basic) the field cannot contains the same name for fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the second `FIELD` declaration overrides the first `FIELD` declaration. In BASIC the variables declared in the `FIELD` statement shall be different.

If you use the code below, you can see an interesting result:

The file testfile.000 will contain 1212 (only the first `LSET` set the field x$ of the file #1)

The file testfile.001 will contain 1488 (both the `LSET` set the field x$ of the file #2).

```
file1$ = "testfile.000"
file2$ = "testfile.001"
OPEN file1$ FOR RANDOM AS #1 LEN = 2
FIELD #1, 2 AS x$
LSET x$ = "12"

OPEN file2$ FOR RANDOM AS #2 LEN = 2
FIELD #2, 2 AS x$
LSET x$ = "14"

PUT #1, 1: REM This puts 12 into the 1st file#1 record.
PUT #2, 1

LSET x$ = "88"
PUT #1, 2: REM this puts 12 into the 2nd file#1 record
PUT #2, 2

CLOSE #1
CLOSE #2
END
```

In QB you may use binary files as in the code below. This mode allows you to write the same variable on more than one file.

When you use this kind of files you will have full control of dimension and position of data into a file.

```
file1$ = "testfile.000"
file2$ = "testfile.001"
OPEN file1$ FOR BINARY AS #1
OPEN file2$ FOR BINARY AS #2

x$ = "29"
PUT #1, 1, x$
PUT #2, 1, x$

CLOSE #1
CLOSE #2
END
```

Comment: That explains a few things to me. Thank you -:)

Comment: @eoredson. If you see this reply as good, set it as a good reply if you aren't waiting for a better reply ... Bye ;)

Comment: No, I say to indicate that this answer is "the answer". But don't care. Bye!

Comment: @eoredson, Ah, ah, ah ... don't care. :) I asked you to click the check that should be below the number of pleas of the answer (there should be a sort a v-check)